# Distribute vertex points around a circle using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working with different datasets imported to Blender and am trying to create a data visualization for each year from 1965 to X year. The years are the attribute index and each year has its values. My idea is to create kind of like an "atom" view so I distribute each year around the circle and the instances are visible in their own line depending on its values.

So I'm wondering if I can get ideas on how to distribute the years around the circle dynamically using Geometry Nodes. For example, if I have 10 years in the spreadsheet, they are automatically arranged (rotated) around the circle, and same if I have datasets with more years.

My idea is to use some node in a similar way the "Count" is on the "Curve to points", so each year (named attribute) is connected and rotated around clockwise. Of course, I couldn't accomplish this.

Thank you in advance!

[image: spreadsheet]

[image: visual idea]

[image: idea]

Comment: _Completely_ BTW, of course, you will have your reasons.. But the representation of _serial_ data as segments of a circle is .. unusual, and open to misinterpretation.   A segmented circle would normally suggest unordered, or possibly cyclic categories. (BTW BTW ..IMO, Edward R Tufte: _The Visual Display of Quantitative Information_ is an absolute classic, and should be in every graphic designer's  collection.)

Comment: @RobinBetts not that either the Q or A are good examples of that, but in many contexts time is cyclic, for example here's a video of the global temperatures calculated by NASA: https://climate.nasa.gov/climate_resources/300/video-climate-spiral-1880-2022/

Comment: Hi, Markus ( My comment is definitely off-topic, but my inner geek gets so mad with badly-represented data.. I have no idea whether this is an example. maybe not at all.. maybe perfectly fine..) The NASA data _are_ cyclic..so the representation is entirely appropriate, and informative. They've also followed one of Tufte's other guiding principles: imagine ink is very expensive, and use as little of it as you can.

Comment: A solution with nodes only is possible in Blender 4.0 using repeat zones, but it's an Alpha version to this moment, and I don't know if answers using non release versions are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to prosecute the guy, who created the addon loading data into named attributes… It's useful, but it's also a noobtrap, leading inexperienced people into unnecessarily hard workflows. One simple and effective way to load data is to create a mesh and set its vertex positions to the data, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299382/60486) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249580/60486).

For example, let's take the data of BSE activity:

[Is there data available on the amount of questions posted over time?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3045/60486)

Save the .csv and convert it to a mesh:

```py
from bpy import context as C, data as D

with open("E:/QueryResults.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

list_1D = []
    
for line in lines[1:]:  # example: "138","5","2013"
    list_1D.extend(map(float, line.replace('"','').split(',')))

me = D.meshes.new('data_mesh')
me.vertices.add(len(list_1D)//3)
me.vertices.foreach_set('co', list_1D)
ob = D.objects.new('data_object', me)
C.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

The code is minimal, since this is a geonodes, not Python question, so the logic is moved to nodes:

[image]

And the effect is a 3D chart, with each cylinder representing a month: cylinders are grouped in year-lines, ordered counter-clockwise starting at $+x$ line for the first year, and the cylinder height is the BSE activity on that month:

[image]