# Geometry node angled line creation

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hello so i'm attempting to make a LED wall mesh generator for virtual production. Hopefully this will all make sense.
I know my panel width is going to be 0.5m the next adjoining panel will be either 0deg,3deg or 5 degree, etc etc. I've got a node set to be able to do it all with the same angle between them. I'm attempting to work out how I would go about being able to define each individual angle.[image: screen creator][image]

Comment: so the angle you are talking about is the z-angle?

Answer (score 1):

the problem with GN right now is, that it doesn't support lists. So tbh i think animation nodes (free add-on) would be much better to perform these kind of tasks then GN in its current state.

But you asked for GN, here is a solution for GN which isn't handy at all...but if you are not using scripting, this is how it could work:

[image]

result:

[image]

Since you didn't tell us which Blender version you are using, i used Blender 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can accumulate angle and then displacement based on angle - below I accumulate also the displacement magnitude to produce a spiral (be aware, there is a node to create a spiral easily):

[image]

Now, in your case it's not clear how you want to evaluate the angle between segments. If you want arbitrary values, then you need to input those arbitrary values somehow into the geometry nodes, here are some examples on how to do it:

**Loading from CSV**

- [How do I assign values from .csv to point position in Geometry Nodes? (Blender 3.4)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299382/60486)
- [Distribute vertex points around a circle using Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/300329/60486)

**Joining single Points**

- [Join points / vertices with a line or curve following an arbitrary given index sequence](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298116/60486)

**Using a String**

- [Geometry Nodes - Extrude edge by ID](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277627/60486) - I'm linking to mine, and not simplified technique by Quellenform, because I remember my technique was bloated specifically because I changed another setup supporting multiple digits to just a binary one, so it might be a good starting point to develop an integer input, but definitely wouldn't suggest for trying with floats (non-integers)

**Color Ramp**

- [Cycling /looping through a set of index values using geometry nodes to create animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274681/60486)
- [How can I rotate individual curve points in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275947/60486)

**Another geometry / Integer input**

- [How to instantiate objects on individual/selected points in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249580/60486)

---

I'm picking a Color Ramp here. It has a limit of 31 swatches (though you could combine multiple Color Ramps… Ask another question if you need that), in this example I'll use a pattern of 10 repeating bends. So first I create a Color Ramp with 10 swatches, no interpolation, and give each swatch the same ($10\%$) cut of the (1-dimensional) pie:

[image]

As you can see, the swatches are distributed evenly at $0.0$, $0.1$, $0.2$ etc. I couldn't just set it to integers, because another limitation of the Color Ramp is that its input is limited to $[0, 1]$ range (or is it $[0, 1)$?) Now in order to translate each index to the related Color Ramp's color, I divide the index by 10, and take the fraction part (after the dot), and add a tiny little $0.001$ just so it doesn't sit exactly on the swatch, because then it's not clear on which side it would end up (I think on the left, but may be subject to floating point errors):

[image]

Yet another limitation of the Color Ramp node: it outputs colors, which are always positive values. So I read the color and subtract $0.5$ from it, making values below $50\%$ grey negative and allowing to bend both ways.

The rest is at the beginning, except I'm using a 1-dimensional grid instead of a curve, as the next step is extruding it:

[image]

[image]

Above I'm first 'removing' the first bend by setting it to $0$ angle (you math think of it as $180°$, but the Color Ramp says it's $0$ in direction change), and then just playing around with two next bends (as well as 11th and 12th bends, because the pattern repeats).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your Answers. I ended up doing it in a bit of a weird way.

So I made an excel to work out the coordinates[image] exported as a CSV.

Used the CSV to blender add-on and then making this geometry node tree.

[image]

Which gives me the result I was looking for.